# How do I remove the WooCommerce Storefront background image after I've deactivated the theme?

Tags: wordpress, storefront

Recently, I've installed the WooCommerce plugin, which of course comes with the Storefront theme. Then, I switched my theme to something else, yet the 'Storefront' image remains on all other themes. It's some variation of a file named 'hero' depending on the resolution (I assume)

How do I remove this permanently from other themes?

(On a side note, isn't this extremely unprofessional - for another theme to have its hooks into all of your Wordpress themes? Also, how can this even happen?)

Comment: `'Storefront' image remains on all other themes`, where is that image appears?

Answer (score 0):

After banging around, I found success in

Appearance->Customize->Content Options->uncheck “Featured Images->Display on Pages”.

Not sure if this is the overall best way, but it seems to work. There are ways you can set a featured image per page, but this is all of my current knowledge of it at this point in time.